# Rest partial response using CXF 3 and Jackson

Tags: json, rest, jackson, cxf, jax-rs

Has anyone implemented Rest partial response (https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_can_your_api_give_developers_just_the_information) using JAX-RS 2 (CXF 3 and Jackson) ?

Comment: Can you explain the a bit for reason behind partial response? Does the processing takes time? or you have large data and you want retrieve in chunks?

Comment: You should be able to implement this using a custom `MessageBodyWriter`